# Issue with Infinite scroll while scrolling upwards UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ueb6gr3Z0xqX5jwm9RMI?p=preview

`<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-infinite-scroll></div>`

This is the plunkr on UI Grid Infinite scroll tutorial (Just made 1 change, replaced lastpage < 4 to 14)

To reproduce the issue:
Keep scrolling down to atleast 7-8 pages. Now when you scroll upwards it is seen that there is no smooth scrolling, the data on the grid changes directly by 100 steps for example when I scroll from 700 to 600 instead of seeing all the records in between I notice a jump of 100 i.e. direct jump from 700 to 600 then directly to 500th record.. then to 400, etc
Please help

Comment: Works for me on firefox 47.0

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Chrome and FF, cant really scroll up having a glance through all the rows.. what I'm seeing is immediate jump of 100 rows sequentially..

Comment: It works OK for me too on Chrome. I scroll way down, then up from 900 to 899, for example, and see rows 895 - 905. Seems correct to me.